# How to scale objects radially, with a time offset?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

Basically what I want to do, is for example the top cube moves up by a few units.  Then the second cube to the right does the same, and then the following cube does the same.  Imagine like a bank vault door opening, with each object moving outwards on a timer.

I didn't want to manually animate these outwards obviously, I imagine there must be an easier way?  Probably with geometry nodes I assume

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try it with this node tree:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: This is amazing!  Thank you so much.  I was overcomplicating it with trying to do something in a straight line with position offsets in geo nodes, then wrapping it, but this makes much more sense.